# Project Euler Problem 18 - Pascal's Triangle

Tags: java, algorithm

**EDIT 2**
I separated out the `offset` code into a new method at Gavin's suggestion:

```
private static int getOffset(int offset, int row, int col, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> triangle, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> p_triangle, ArrayList<Integer> sums) {
    int row_num = (row+1); //= 1-indexed row #
    int p_value = p_triangle.get(row).get(col); // number from pascal's triangle

    if (col > 1)  {
        // element is in the left half of Pascal's Triangle
        if (col <= (row_num/2))       offset++;
        // penultimate element
        else if (col == row_num - 2)  offset = sums.size() - p_value;
        // elements halfway until penultimate;
        // [-2, -3] all work up until row 10 and fail thereafter
        else                          offset = sums.size() - p_value - (row_num - col - 2);
    }

    return offset;
  }
```

And found that, oddly enough, subtracting 2 or 3 both work when calculating the offset for an element in the latter half of the given row (between halfway and antepenultimate). And I have no idea why that's the case.

Even stranger is that I modified Oleg's answer

```
public static int findMaxSum(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> data) {
    for (int row = data.size() - 2; row >= 0; row--)
      for (int col = 0; col < data.get(row).size(); col++)
        data.get(row).set(col, data.get(row).get(col) + Math.max(data.get(row + 1).get(col), data.get(row + 1).get(col + 1)));

    return data.get(0).get(0);
  }
```

and found that the behavior of algorithm appears to be correct up to a triangle of size 10. However, it starts to breakdown after that with the following discrepancies in rows 11-15:

```
size = 11 [correct:772 | mine:752]
size = 12 [correct:850 | mine:830]
size = 13 [correct:908 | mine:921]
size = 14 [correct:981 | mine:961]
size = 15 [correct:1074 | mine:1059]
```

Unfortunately, I still can't discern a pattern from this.

**EDIT**
I'd like to emphasize that I'm not looking for a better way to solve this particular Project Euler problem; instead, I just want to know if it's possible to use Pascal's Triangle to do it in the way I described (or in some slightly modified way) and if someone can see the logic in my code I may be blind to.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I am trying to solve [Project Euler problem 18](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18).

The goal is to find the max sum of all the 2^14 paths down a triangle of numbers.

I was struck by the similarity with Pascal's Triangle and wondered if it could be used to solve the problem.

My logic is as follows:

1.) Calculate the sums by row.
2.) Use Pascal's triangle to determine how many there must be (as each row adds up to a power of two) and to determine the offset from the start of the of the previous rows sums.

Ex.

```
Pascal's Triangle
   1
  1 1
 1 2 1
1 3 3 1
```

```
Triangle To Process
   3
  7 4
 2 4 6
8 5 9 3
```

```
Sums
              [3]
            [10, 7]
        [12, 14, 11, 13]
[20, 17, 19, 16, 23, 20, 22, 16]
```

For row 3, we see Pascal's Triangle informs us that there will be 1 + 2 + 1 or 4 values. Furthermore, it describes how to build the sums because it's the first and last element added to the sum directly preceding them and the middle value added to both of those sums as it has contact with both the preceding chains.

By extension, the fourth row shows that the second number in the Triangle to Process should be added to the first three sums from row three and the third number should be added to the final three.

The way I get the offset is kind of ugly (and maybe the source of the trouble):

```
if (i > 1)  {
  if (i < (p_triangle.get(row).size()/2))   offset++;
  else if (i == triangle.get(row).size()-2) offset = sums.size() - p_triangle.get(row).get(i);
  else  offset = sums.size() - p_triangle.get(row).get(i) - (p_triangle.get(row).size() - i - 2);
}
```

Where `p_triangle.get(row)` is the current Pascal's Triangle row being used, `sums` is the array of cumulative sums (2^(row-1) in length), offset is where to start the summations from, and the Pascal's Triangle number is how many elements from the sum list starting at the offset to sum the number at index i in the Triangle to Process, i.e., `triangle.get(row).get(i)`.

I know this may not be the most efficient algorithm to solve the problem, but it seems like it could be a nice one. The thing is, I can't get it to work.

**SPOILER ALERT ON THE ANSWER TO THE PROBLEM**
The correct answer is apparently 1074

Can anyone tell me where in the code or in my logic for using Pascal's Triangle, I might have messed up?

THE FULL CODE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.lang.Math;

public class MaxPathSum {


  private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> pascalsTriangle(int n_rows) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> triangle = new ArrayList<>();
    triangle.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(1);}});
    triangle.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(1); add(1);}});

    for (int row = 2; row < n_rows; row++) {
      ArrayList<Integer> next_row = new ArrayList<>();
      next_row.add(1);
      for (int i = 1; i < triangle.get(row-1).size(); i++) {
        next_row.add(triangle.get(row-1).get(i-1) + triangle.get(row-1).get(i));
      }
      next_row.add(1);
      triangle.add(next_row);
    }
    return triangle;
  }

  private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> buildTriangle(int n_rows) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> triangle = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int row = 1; row <= n_rows; row++) {
      ArrayList<Integer> row_arr = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int elem = 1; elem <= row; elem++) {
        row_arr.add(sc.nextInt());
      }
      triangle.add(row_arr);
    }
    return triangle;
  }


  private static int findLargestSum(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> triangle, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> p_triangle) {
    ArrayList<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<>();
    sums.add(triangle.get(0).get(0));

    // traverse the rows
    for (int row = 1, offset = 0; row < triangle.size(); row++, offset = 0) {
      ArrayList<Integer> new_sums = new ArrayList<>();
      
      // traverse each element in each row
      new_sums.add(sums.get(0) + triangle.get(row).get(0));
      for (int i = 1; i < triangle.get(row).size()-1; i++) {
        int n_times = p_triangle.get(row).get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < n_times; j++) {
          new_sums.add(triangle.get(row).get(i) + sums.get(j+offset));
        }
        if (i > 1)  {
          if (i < (p_triangle.get(row).size()/2))   offset++;
          else if (i == triangle.get(row).size()-2) offset = sums.size() - p_triangle.get(row).get(i);
          else  offset = sums.size() - p_triangle.get(row).get(i) - (p_triangle.get(row).size() - i - 2);

          System.out.println("Row: " + row + " | Offset: " + offset);
        }
      }
      new_sums.add(sums.get(sums.size()-1) + triangle.get(row).get(triangle.get(row).size()-1));
      sums = new_sums;
    }

    Collections.sort(sums);
    return sums.get(sums.size() - 1);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n_rows = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    // build pascalsTriangle
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> p_triangle = pascalsTriangle(n_rows);

    // build triangle from input
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> triangle = buildTriangle(n_rows);

    // traverse triangle finding largest sum
    int largest_sum = findLargestSum(triangle, p_triangle);

    // display results
    System.out.println(largest_sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you suspect the code to get the offset is your issue, perhaps if you changed your code slightly such that you can test the code the determines the offset in isolation might help.  This could be done by putting that in a method that returns the offset and testing the method.

Comment: That's a good idea. I erased a bunch of logging ```System.out.println()``` to try to make the code less of a mess. I did print out the offset and as far as I could tell (at least at the lower rows) it seemed right to me. That's why I was wondering if my logic was off.

Comment: I think in this instance, testing will give better results than trying to understand the log output.  Another possibility is debugging, again that might be easier if the offset code is in its own method.

Comment: @Gavin I'll try as you say to separate it out into its own function and see what I can do from there.

Answer (score 1):

Just be simple!

```java
public static int findMaxSum(int[][] data) {
    for (int row = data.length - 2; row >= 0; row--)
        for (int col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++)
            data[row][col] += Math.max(data[row + 1][col], data[row + 1][col + 1]);

    return data[0][0];
}
```